# How do I stop a d3 object from returning to zero at every update?

Tags: php, html, d3.js

Making a compass in d3 I have created an arrow that will transition
around a circle, upon every update of a new angle the arrow always returns to zero
first then moves to the new angle.
How do I avoid the arrow returning to zero every update ?

> 

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<style>
.arrowgreen {
 margin-top: 12.5px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
.circ {
 margin-top: -145px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
</style>
 
<div class="arrowgreen">
<svg width="140" height="140" style="border:0px solid green" id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 140 140"></svg>
</div>
<div class="circ"> 
<svg width="140" height="140" style="border:0px solid blue" id="circ" viewBox="0 0 140 140"></svg>
</div>


<script>

var angle = 180; // "<?php echo $wind["direction"];?>";  

var svg = d3.select("#circ")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("height", 140)            
        .attr("width", 140)
        .append("g");
            
    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 70) // center circle
        .attr("cy", 70)
        .style("stroke", "rgba(59, 60, 63, 1)")
        .style("stroke-width", "7")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .attr("r", 60);

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 70)
        .attr("y", 74)
        .style("fill", "silver")
        .style("font-family", "Helvetica")
        .style("font-size", "11px")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-weight", "normal")
        .text(angle+"°");   
      
var dataArrow = [[70, 22], [75, 2], [70, 8], [65, 2]];
  
var lineGenerator = d3.line();
var pathString = lineGenerator(dataArrow);
 
var compassArrow = d3.select("#arrow")
        compassArrow.append("path")
        .attr('d', pathString)    
        .attr("fill", "rgba(0,127,255,1)")
        compassArrow.transition()
        .ease(d3.easePoly)
        .duration(1500)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ", 0, 0)");
```

I did find a possible solution but this would break the transition duration

Comment: I [tried to use your code](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/mdKmNNy), but I see nothing. Yes, I did use the D3 library. How can we help if your code doesn't do anything?

Comment: I have just added the css, KIKO Software I have just seen that you put all the d3.js code in the css part in your codepen.io test I'm not sure that would work please try again with the added css

Comment: Ah, [it's working now](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/mdKmNNy), I also mistakenly put the JS in the CSS box...

Comment: Here is my demo you can see the problem (bottom right) module is set to update every 4 seconds https://skynetweather.com/html/weather34/index.php

Answer (score 0):

OK, i cobbled something together using a promise. This is not perfect by any means, but it work. See: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/mdKmNNy

The bit that makes this work is:

```
compassArrow.append("path")
        .attr('d', pathString)    
        .attr("fill", "rgba(0,127,255,1)")
compassArrow.transition()
        .ease(d3.easePoly)
        .duration(1500)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ", 0, 0)")
        .end()
        .then( function () {
     angle = 10;
     compassArrow.transition()
        .ease(d3.easePoly)
        .duration(1500)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ", 0, 0)");
          
});
```

Basically I wait for the first animation to finish with `.end()`, and then I execute the next animation.

See: [How to use promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: @4500X-RAY I did note that after the second animation the middle of the compass still says 180 degrees, but I'm sure you can do something about that. Chaining, like I did, is not very practical anyway, but promises are very flexible by nature.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem, even replacing angle = 10; with angle = angle; you can see on my demo module link is above.

Comment: @4500X-RAY You're refreshing the whole compass every few seconds, including the Javascript code. This will never work if you do it like that.

Comment: Ok understood, unless I find another way to do this I may bin the idea. The main compass on my template works fine it's just I wanted to find a way to transition the arrow instead of simply jumping from one angle to the next. Thanks for trying and the the tip, I will leave the link here for everyone to see the weather template. https://skynetweather.com/html/weather34/index.php